# File contains both CRLF and also LF. I want to delete CRLF

Tags: sed, tr

I have a file that contains both CRLF in it and also LF in it. I am trying to delete the CRLF from my file. The other pre-existing LF in my file, I would like to remain behind. I'm having trouble because either it seems sed can't identify CRLF, or because tr delete both CRLF and LF at the same time. I've trie,

```
tr -d '\r\n' <file.txt> file2.txt
```

it is also deleting the LF in my file as well. I tried deleting only \r but then the LF from the CRLF gets left behind. I want CRLF to be deleted or at least turned into a space, but the row doesn't end.

Any help?

I've tried:

```
tr -d '\r\n' <file.txt> file2.txt
```

I've tried sed as well but I'm not able to find CRLF.

Comment: "_I tried deleting only \r but then the LF gets left behind._"  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I meant the LF from the CRLF gets left behind. So the CRLF becomes LF, leaving the end of line. I want the CRLF to disappear, or worst case get turned into a space ' ' or something.

Comment: So, what does the first sentence of the question mean: `I am trying to remove CRLF from my file, but keep the LF.`

Comment: Gotcha. I can see how I'm not being clear. Edited to have "I have a file that contains both CRLF in it and also LF in it. I am trying to delete the CRLF from my file. The other pre-existing LF in my file, I would like to remain behind."

Answer (score 1):

This will convert dos format file to linux/unix format.

```
dos2unix file
```

Comment: The OP wants to delete `\r\n` not turn it into `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `tr` is a list of **characters** to operate on, not a string, so `\r\n` means `\r` or `\n`, not `\r` followed by `\n`. sed by default cant remove `\r\n` because sed reads one `\n`-terminated line at a time so there's never `\r\n` in seds buffer, just the `\r` after the `\n` was removed by sed reading the line.

You can do this with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS= '1' file
```

or with GNU sed for `-z` (but this will read the whole file into memory at once):

```
sed -z 's/\r\n//g' file
```